# Loading resource id with Glide returns a noModelLoaderAvailableException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-resources, android-glide

As far as I have seen, the way to load images via Resource Id is the same as loading normally from the internet:

```java
Glide.with(fragmentContext).load(R.id.drawable).into(imageView);
```

(Although the way I'm loading it is slightly different, as I have dynamic resource images)

```java
Glide.with(fragmentContext).load(R.drawable.class.getField("image_path_" + model.modelID))
    .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
            textView.setBackground(resource);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            textView.setBackground(placeholder);
        }
    });
```

My image I'm trying to load is a .jpg saved in the drawable-nodpi folder.

When attempting to load the image in the `onBindViewHolder` in my recycler adapter, I get the following error:

```
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: public static final int com.example.me.project.R$drawable.image
```

Does this have to do with my image format, or where it's saved in my assets/resource folders?  I don't believe I have to implement a complex Model Loader for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `getField()` snippet works when setting the resource of a View element, it doesn't work on Glide, as it expects specifically a `resource Id`, which is an `int`. Type `Field` != `Int`.

In this instance you have to explicitly get the Int resource Id from the resource.

Here would be the updated code to work with glide's image loader:

`R.drawable.class.getField("name").getInt(null)`